# How to set basePath for a static exported NextJS app

Tags: javascript, next.js, war

I need to build and deploy a React / NextJS app to a Weblogic J2ee server with a specific context. I have some React experience, but taking my first steps with NextJS.

Currently the build/verification steps are;

- Create a vanilla NextJS app
- Add a `next.config.js` with a `module.export` to change the basepath

  module.exports = {
  basePath: '/test'
  }
- Execute `npm run dev` the application is available on 'http://localhost:3000/test'
- Add an export script to the package.json `"export": "next build && next export"` to support static export
- Add the export below to resolve issue 21079

  ```
  //https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/21079
  module.exports = {
    images: {
      loader: "imgix",
      path: "",
    }
  }
  ```

- Executed `npm run export` to create a static HTML export. Export is completed successfully to the `out` folder.
  When inspecting the `index.html` in the `out` folder, all references to the static content still starts with `/_next/static` and not with `/test/_next/static`.

  So this can be a misinterpretation of my side, please correct me if i am wrong here.
- To be able to test the vanilla app on the J2EE applicationserver it has to be packed into a war file. To accomplish this i added the file `warpack/warpack.ts` to the project.

```js
    const fs = require('fs');
    const archiver = require('archiver');
    const rimraf = require('rimraf') ;
    
    const distFolder = 'dist' ;
    const warFile = distFolder + '/test.war';
    const buildFolder = 'out';
    const contextRoot = 'test';
    
    // Destroy dist folder
    rimraf(distFolder, (error) => { 
        if (!error) {       
            // Create dist folder
            if (!fs.existsSync(distFolder)){
                fs.mkdirSync(distFolder);
            }
        
            const output = fs.createWriteStream(warFile);
            const archive = archiver('zip', {});
        
            output.on('close', () => {
                console.log('war (' + warFile + ') ' + archive.pointer() + ' total bytes');
            });
        
            // write archive to output file
            archive.pipe(output);
            // add build folder to archive
            archive.directory(buildFolder,'');
            // add weblogic.xml
            const weblogicXML = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><weblogic-web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app/1.2/weblogic-web-app.xsd"><weblogic-version>10.3.6</weblogic-version><context-root>' + contextRoot '</context-root><description>Test NextJS</description></weblogic-web-app>'
            archive.append(weblogicXML,{ name: 'WEB-INF/weblogic.xml' });
        
            const manifestMF = 'Manifest-Version: 1.0\nBuild-Tag: 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT\nWeblogic-Application-Version: 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT';
            archive.append(manifestMF,{ name: 'META-INF/MANIFEST.MF' });
        
            archive.finalize();
        
        } else {
            console.log('Failed to delete "' + distFolder + '" folder.') ;
            process.exit(1);
        };
    });
```

- Installed the required packages for `webpack.ts`

  npm install fs --save-dev
  npm install rimraf --save-dev
  npm install archiver --save-dev
- Added the script `"warpack": "next build && next export && node warpack/warpack.ts"` to build, export and pack the static app to an war.
- After deployment of the war-file the page can be loaded on `http://something/test` but shows an empty page.
  Network development tools indicate that the requests are made to the root of the application server, not to the configured basepath.

  ```
    GET http://host:8001/static/css/main.09371e9d.chunk.css     net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
    GET http://host/static/js/2.0850eeb7.chunk.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
    GET http://host/static/js/main.dc0c945b.chunk.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
  ```

​

Answer (score 4):

You can use `env` check to invoke only for `prod` environment if you wish to like:

```
module.exports = {
    basePath: "/test"
    assetPrefix: process.env.NODE_ENV === "production" ? "/test/" : undefined,
}
```

Comment: Thanks, exactly the plain and simple answer I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

Too much focus on basePath value instead on correct syntax of `next.config.js`.
Second module export in `next.config.js` overwrote first.

### Wrong

```
module.exports = { 
  basePath: '/test' 
}

//https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/21079
module.exports = {
  images: {
    loader: "imgix",
    path: "",
  }
}
```

### Correct

```
module.exports = { 
  basePath: '/test',
  assetPrefix: "/test/",

  //https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/21079
  images: {
    loader: "imgix",
    path: ""
  }

}
```

Comment: i want to run export files in direct admin , work fine but after refresh retrun error 404