# Next.js 13 basePath doesn't work when generating static files: pointing to the root in stead of subfolder

Tags: typescript, next.js, next.js13, tsconfig

Following the docs at https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/api-reference/next-config-js/basePath, I have put the following in `tsconfig.json` to generate a static version of my Next.JS v13.5.4 webpage:

```
  {
  "compilerOptions": {
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["./src/*"],
    },
    "baseUrl": "https://www.website.com/subfolder/subfolder",
  },
  "basePath": "/subfolder/subfolder",
  "assetPrefix": "https://www.website.com/subfolder/subfolder/",
}
```

But, when looking at the generated index.html file, it stays blank. That's because the generated files (links, assets, images) point to the root of the website. Example:

```
<script src="/_next/static/chunks/webpack-3dedf0bbbe0af454.js" async=""></script>
```

Well, that doesn't work, because those files aren't there in the `/out` folder. Is there any way to generate a static website with **NextJS 13** - or is it mandatory to setup a VPS server to host it in a Node JS / docker container or something?

Comment: The only way I got it to work was to follow do what was suggested in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74367470/1959719) but I would prefer if there was a way to do something similar to what you are showing. It would make it easier to build and deploy.